# Calendar is displayed multiple times

Tags: javascript

On a website the following should be displayed:
Text about first apartment + availability calendar
Text about second apartment + availability calendar
The problem is that the first availability calendar appears twice.
How can I show each calendar only once?

```
<p>Text about first apartment 104081</p>

<div class="iw-bookingwidget"></div> <script id="iw-bookingwidgetScript" type="text/javascript" src="https://www.buchen.travel/shared/_expo/js-scripts/jquery.responsiveIframeComplete.js" data-room="104081" data-onlythisroom="1" data-interfaceid="79997" data-cal="only" data-url="https://bookingwidget.im-web.de" ></script>

<p>Text about second apartment 104080</p>

<div class="iw-bookingwidget"></div> <script id="iw-bookingwidgetScript" type="text/javascript" src="https://www.buchen.travel/shared/_expo/js-scripts/jquery.responsiveIframeComplete.js" data-room="104080" data-onlythisroom="1" data-interfaceid="79998" data-cal="only" data-url="https://bookingwidget.im-web.de" ></script>
```

Comment: @MaximeGirou it was well hidden inside the question ;-)

Comment: I'm not sure but you  use same `id`  for both. Try  to do them  different.

Answer (score 0):

The script you're including has the following in it:

```
jQuery.each(jQuery("#iw-bookingwidgetScript").data(), function(key,value) {
                switch(key){
                    case "cal":
                        switch(value){
                            case"all":
                                iwVar.bookingcalendar_all = "1";
                            break;
                            case"only":
                                iwVar.bookingcalendar_only = "1";
                            break;
                        }
                    break;
                    case "url":                 
                        iwVarUrl = value;
                    break;
                default:
                    iwVar[key] = value;
                }
            });
```

Becuase both your tags have the same ID and you're including the script twice, it is outputting the calendar twice.

Remove one of the script tags and visually it works correctly.

Comment: Using the same `id` twice is invalid HTML. As well as removing the second script, it would also be worth switching over to using classes for non-unique elements.